# Flink: Dataset and Datastream API in one program. Is it possible?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to first manipulate static data using dataset API and then use DataStream API to run a streaming job. If I write code on IDE, it works perfectly. But when I try running on local flink jobmanager (all parallelism 1), the streaming code never executes!

For example, the following code is not working:

```
val parallelism = 1

val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setParallelism(parallelism)

val envStatic = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
envStatic.setParallelism(parallelism)

val myStaticData = envStatic.fromCollection(1 to 10)
val myVal: Int = myStaticData.reduce(_ + _).collect().head

val theStream = env.fromElements(1).iterate( iteretion => {
  val result = iteretion.map(x => x + myVal)
  (result, result)
})
theStream.print()
env.execute("static and streaming together")
```

What should I try to get this thing working?

Logs:[execution logs for above program](http://students.iitmandi.ac.in/~vishal_goel/log.txt)

Execution plan: [plan](http://students.iitmandi.ac.in/~vishal_goel/plan.png)
Seems to be a-cyclic.

Comment: What are the logs saying?

Comment: @TillRohrmann Link added.

Comment: What does the client log say?

Comment: @TillRohrmann ran on local job manager. *.out file is empty. The job directly finishes.

Comment: @TillRohrmann the execution plan created by job manager seems to a-cyclic! [link](http://students.iitmandi.ac.in/~vishal_goel/plan.png)

Comment: But you submitted the job via the cli? The job is fine. There is a source and sink operator, and thus no cycle.

Comment: @TillRohrmann I uploaded the jar to web UI and specified the class. Create plan and submited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108919/discussion-between-vishal-goel-and-till-rohrmann).

Comment: Job submission via the web interface does not support multiple jobs in one jar. You therefore have to submit your job via the CLI to execute the your job properly. Note that the `collect` method implicitly triggers a job execution.

Comment: Client Log after running via command line: [link](http://students.iitmandi.ac.in/~vishal_goel/clientLog.txt). I thought for streaming context, I will need separate trigger.

Comment: @TillRohrmann submitting via command line, writing to a file and everything is working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Flink job which consists of multiple sub jobs, e.g. triggered by `count`, `collect` or `print`, then you cannot submit the job via the web interface. The web interface only supports a single Flink job.